# Hazard ratio using stpm2 package in R

Tags: r, model, survival

I am trying to plot hazard ratio plot for 1/0 type of medicine for the following data. My data looks like following.

cancer

time event typeofmed
12   1     1
15   0     1
13   1     0
11   1     0

I am not sure what goes in tvc.

```
fpmh <- stpm2(Surv(time,event) ~ typeofmed,
        data=cancer, tvc=list(?????),
        df=4)
summary(fpmh)

med <- levels(cancer$typeofmed)
newdata1 <- data.frame(typeofmed=med[1])
plot(fpmh, newdata=newdata1, xlab="Time since diagnosis (years)", 
     type="haz")
plot(fpmh, newdata=newdata1, xlab="Time since diagnosis (years)",
 type="hr",var="typeofmed", ci=FALSE, ylim=c(0,6))
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use the `stpm2` function? There is the base R `coxph(Surv(time,event) ~ typeofmed, data = cancer)` function which you should be able to use to fit a proportional hazards model.

Comment: What isn't clear from the documentation? "A list with the names of the time-varying coefficients and the degrees of freedom (e.g. `tvc=list(x=3)` specifies `x` as a time-varying coefficient with 3 degrees of freedom)."